# iPhone: How do I "cancel" my xmlparser from parsing in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

In my

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
        didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
           namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
          qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
             attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
          // ...
}
```

I check to see if one of my XML attributes is equal to a value I store in my plist. If it's not then I want it to execute normally and get the latest information. If it is the same value though I don't want to waste the processing time of getting all the data again.  So if I have code like below how can I terminate the parsing process if the values are the same?

```
if (lastUpdated == [attributeDict valueForKey:@"last_updated"]) {
     // Terminate the xml parsing because data is up to date
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[parser abortParsing]` but note that this is intended for XML errors rather than "I don't want this data" situations and can cause your `parser:parseErrorOcurred:` method to be called a couple of times, in my experience.

Comment: I don't think it's `parser:didFailWithError` I believe its `parser:parseErrorOccurred` ... at least that's what I'm using I couldn't find a reference to `parser:didFailWithError`

Answer (score 1):

Call [parser abortParsing] to cancel parsing from current point.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that there is a bug in iOS 6.0 and abortParsing will cancel the parser but will not call parser:parseErrorOccurred and will not set 'parserError'.